# Debugging the android kernel

Tags: android, debugging, kernel

I want to start looking at the workings of the Linux kernel on an android device and also write some device drivers. I am used to writing drivers for Window, and the book on Linux drivers seems to make sense. My problem is that I do not have a clue how to set up a remote debugging session so that I can debug kernel code / drivers on the Android system. Being a Windows person at heart and not a Linux one, I am struggling.

I have rooted the Android device, built and installed CyangenMod from source code. I have checked that the build config had the right options enabled for kernel debugging (kprobes/ debug file system / Compile with debug info).

I have seen mention of GDB and KGDB, but do not know how to set them up. I have seen different web pages and even a youtube video from Chinese fellow, but did not find them easy to follow. Some of the descriptions talk about connecting a serial cable between the two computers. Something you can not do on an Android system.

I presume that you have to install a module on the target machine, a frontend debugger on the host machine, point the debugger at the relevant kernel source and symbol tables and then place hard coded breakpoints in the kernel code.

Could someone give me an idiot's guide on how to do this.

Comment: Many android devices have low-voltage serial ports which can be enabled by kernel changes and special cabling; it should also be possible to have a special module for managing the USB for this purpose instead of the usual stack topped by adb.  Generally though, interactive debugging is a last restort - you write your code correctly, make incremental changes, and verify using printk() type logging.  For procedural rather than hardware-related work you can also consider debugging in the QEMU-based emulator, or on an ARM development board with better I/O.

Comment: The best solution: target -> UART (RS232 for example) -> PC.
A good solution: adb shell dmesg (quite suitable for lightweight drivers).
But in general it is strange that you are able to do so mach without reading LDD3 [Chapter 4](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch04.pdf)